# Property that is set by event handler is always displayed without change

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a simple function that is called every second using `setInterval`,

I have to change the value to say if there is mouse or keyboard activity.

I update the value of my variable but it's always set as 0 even though the `console.log` are called.

```
function generateActivity() {
    var o = { is_mouse: 0, is_keyboard: 0 };

    // Keyboard activity
    uiohook.uIOhook.on('keydown', (e) => {
        //console.log('Keyboard!')
         o.is_keyboard = 1;
    })

    // Mouse activity
    uiohook.uIOhook.on('mousemove', (e) => {
        //console.log('mouse');
        o.is_mouse = 1;
    })

    console.log(o);
}

setInterval(generateActivity, 1*1000);
```

Comment: Log inside callbacks and then check value

Comment: check where your variable is, you are reseting it every time you call the function, move the var outside

Comment: are you calling `generateActivity` every second? surely you just want to call it once to set the listeners and then rely on them for update

Comment: I have to reset the variable because every second could be not especially 1, could also be 0.

Comment: You are going to flood the system with listeners on keys and mouse moves. Each second you add 2 more... This is going to crash at some point in time. Secondly, you will have as many `o` objects as `generateActivity` is called. Each initialised with zeroes. And you output it immediately without waiting for the user interaction.

Comment: What do you guys recommend to do? I'm a bit lost

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should set up your listeners only once, not every second -- they accumulate, so this is going to give problems.

Secondly, your `o` object should not be created locally every second, which will give you as many objects as calls made. It should be a single object.

Something like this:

```
var o = { is_mouse: 0, is_keyboard: 0 };

// Keyboard activity
uiohook.uIOhook.on('keydown', (e) => {
    //console.log('Keyboard!')
     o.is_keyboard = 1;
})

// Mouse activity
uiohook.uIOhook.on('mousemove', (e) => {
    //console.log('mouse');
    o.is_mouse = 1;
})

function generateActivity() {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(o)); // Make sure the object is displayed as we want it.
    o.is_mouse = o.is_keyboard = 0; // maybe reset after logging...
}

setInterval(generateActivity, 1*1000);
```

Note that I have stringified the object for output, as otherwise the console may display it lazily, showing the 0 that was put in the properties after `console.log` was called.